# How to update a-GPS data on iOS / iPhone?

Tags: ios, gps

On android devices you can have apps download/update the aGPS data to improve fix times when your device starts getting old (Alas, the aGPS gets outdated).

How to do so on iOS/iPhone? Some old iPhone 4 have terrible fix times probably because of old AGPS and all I can get people to tell me is to reset the phone ... there has to be a better way? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, and not neccesarry.
(my iphone4 has a Time To First fix  of not so terrible 15s, when having an internet connection)
What is a terrible Time to first fix (TTF) value for you? Ho many seconds?

iphone4 uses GPS only, while later iphones additonalay use GLONASS.
This duplicates the number o f visisble satelites, which is especially in urban canyons an advantage. This also reduces the TTF time.

So the cause of bad TTF times is based by the fact that the iphone4 use GPS satellites only,
combined with very bad view to sky.

It also depends of the software/ your app, e.g taking a network location (cell tower) in android, you should not compare with a GPS location in ios.

Comment: With clear skies, 2 minutes for TTF is terrible right? a brand new iPhone 6 at it's side will TTF in 10 seconds. iPhone, all versions, use aGPS, which uses a small database of satellite positions to improve TTF. If the database is old, it becomes useless or can increase TTF. And I am comparing only GPS, no cell tower improvement enabled if I compare with android (also get like 10~20s with a S4 on same spot)